# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

Since I migrated to Android X, WebView has not worked and the app is constantly shutting down.
This is my logcat:

```
I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 4504 ms (timestamps 275-4779)
I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {164a72fb}
I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(65)] Load from apk succesful, fd=48 off=46184 len=3037
I/chromium: [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:49 off:229484 len:1089587
W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(331)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x02040003
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/ACRA: ACRA caught a RuntimeException for ir.ari.book
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.ari.book/ir.ari.book.ShowContent}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at ir.ari.book.ShowContent.onCreate(ShowContent.java:178)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at ir.ari.book.ShowContent.onCreate(ShowContent.java:178) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:385)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setContainerView(ContentViewCore.java:684)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.initialize(ContentViewCore.java:608)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.createAndInitializeContentViewCore(AwContents.java:631)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.setNewAwContents(AwContents.java:780)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:619)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:556)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.initForReal(WebViewChromium.java:311)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.access$100(WebViewChromium.java:96)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:263)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.drainQueue(WebViewChromium.java:123)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:110)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:144)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.addTask(WebViewChromium.java:107)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:260)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:554)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:489)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.ja
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10864 SIG: 9
Process 10864 terminated.
```

It means android find a resource but can't find it.
I tested it in Nox launcher with Android Lollipop. Also I tested it with androidx and android support; with android support, haven't any problem, but with androidx have this problem. Also I tested it into another device with Android KitKat and successfully worked without any problem.

Comment: Where is your layout containing `WebView`?

Comment: CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Please add your xml containing `WebView`

Comment: <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a custome WebView class:

```
    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context) {
        super(getFixedContext(context));
    }

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs);
    }

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, boolean privateBrowsing) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr, privateBrowsing);
    }

    public static Context getFixedContext(Context context) {
        return context.createConfigurationContext(new Configuration());
    }
}
```

Than I changed WebView tag to LollipopFixedWebView. It's worked for me.